# Why can't I eject ramdisk on OSX?

Tags: macos, filesystems, ramdisk

I followed these instructions for creating a ramdisk on OSX. Now I can't unmount the disk despite not using it (lsof verifies nothing is using the disk).

Instructions to create:

```
$ hdid -nomount ram://32768
$ newfs_hfs /dev/disk1
$ mkdir /tmp/ramdisk1
$ mount -t hfs /dev/disk1 /tmp/ramdisk1
```

To unmount (does NOT work):

```
hdiutil detach /dev/disk1
```

The message I get is:

```
"disk1" unmounted.
hdiutil: couldn't eject "disk1" - Resource busy
```

The `-force` switch has no effect. Also, issuing the command as root has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you umounted it with `umount /tmp/ramdisk1` first?
`hdiutil detach` only removes device, but doesn't aware about mount points.